# Use GROUP BY with additional clause

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

My structure table:

[image: Structure Table]

I want to search the average score each siswa, each mapel and each ranah, but just for komponen = PR, tugas, ulangan.

I tried this :

```
    SELECT `nama_siswa`, `mapel`, avg(nilai) FROM nilai_coba 
GROUP BY `nama_siswa`, `mapel`, `ranah`, `komponen`='pr' AND 'tugas' AND 'ulangan'
```

but the value of UTS and UAS komponen goes counted to the average result too .

[image: Excel screenshot]

In here (red circle), avg values is 79.09. calculated from PR, tugas, ulangan, UTS, and UAS. It should be 76,7 for Ana in mapel PKN. The blue circle is my Excel data, where NH = (xPR+xTugas+xUH)/3

I tried using Having too, but I guess it is still not correct.
So, how I can get the avg for ana in Pkn is 76,7?

If I can't tell my question clearly, I hope the Excel screenshot can help :(

Comment: can you please post the expected output and obviously your correct won't work

Comment: @maSTAShuFu edited. how the correct syntax for counting NH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the start for your query, regardless of database you are using:

```
SELECT komponen, AVG(nilai) AS nilai_average
FROM nilai_coba 
WHERE komponen IN ('pr', 'tugas', 'ulangan')
GROUP BY komponen
ORDER BY komponen
```

That will show you the average score for just those komponen. If you use the following query:

```
SELECT komponen, nama_siswa, mapel, ranah, AVG(nilai) AS nilai_average
FROM nilai_coba 
WHERE komponen IN ('pr', 'tugas', 'ulangan')
GROUP BY komponen, nama_siswa, mapel, ranah
ORDER BY komponen
```

then you will see the average broken down across all of those fields.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your addition of the Excel spreadsheet, this should get you the NH:

```
SELECT nama_siswa, mapel, AVG(nilai) AS nilai_average
FROM nilai_coba
WHERE komponen IN ('pr', 'tugas', 'ulangan')
GROUP BY nama_siswa, mapel
ORDER BY nama_siswa, mapel
```

I am assuming that for NH you don't want those values divided by three, but you actually want the average. Note that this method will only be able to get you the NH for each unique nama_siswa and mapel. If you want the SQL query to give you a result formatted like the Excel spreadsheet, you should look into PIVOT functions.

Comment: thanks @SandPiper . i edited my question. actually i want to count the NH.. How the correct syntax should be?

Comment: thankyou so muuuuch for ur help. and im going to learn bout Pivot now.